# MySQL "Access Denied" in xampp v3.2.2

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP and am unable to connect to MySQL to create a password.

When I attempt to connect, I get the error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

[image: mysql connection error]

Comment: You're specifying the password incorrectly.  Does it work if you use `mysqladmin -u root -p admin`, or simply `mysqladmin -u root`?